# Android Development Android Studio Problem

Tags: android

Hey I'm doing android development with jetpack compose but i'm not able to implement some properties of modifiers like from where i'm watching  I have written same code but during using some keywords or some properties showing error hen i'm using that.

Are there any resource from that I can learn from basics as beginner?

Comment: Sorry but we can not help you with "some" problems, but if you would edit your question and describe in detail what is going wrong somebody here may be able to help you  ;)